# What is the best way to install a C# windows service that doesn't require running installutil manually?

Tags: windows-services, setup-project, installutil

I'd like to package a C# windows service project so it can be easily installed by anyone without having to use installutil command prompt utility? Is there an easy way to configure a Visual Studio setup project to do that similar to how winforms applications are installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to create a install project to get a nice and clean MSI installer, this should help you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169

And codeproject has a good example too: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of extra answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255056/install-a-net-windows-service-without-installutil-exe).

If the app is for basic users then the MSI is the best way to go.

If it's aimed at techies then I personally prefer apps that can install and uninstall themselves, and can run as a service or like a normal app. The linked question has answers that describe this.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sakes I'll summarise http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169 here.

You need to add a Service Installer class to your service component.  This can then be called by the setup routine to add you service.  You'll need to create a custom action in your Setup project to call it.  The details are in the KB identified.