# C#: Making an Installer that installs both a WPF application (ClickOnce) and a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, clickonce

I currently have a VS Solution with 2 projects: a WPF application and a Windows Service.

Now, I have managed to get ClickOnce working in installing my WPF application, but I also want a Windows Service to be installed (the one in the project) during this installation.

I have found ways how to programmatically start a windows service with C# code, but is there any way to incorporate this in my ClickOnce installation (because I need ClickOnce's benefit of automatic updates and such)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can deploy a windows service via ClickOnce in a normal fashion.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/1bb64760-9622-4ca6-a1a6-3ce53e641f21

[ClickOnce deploy a Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460118/clickonce-deploy-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 2):

Please check [DDay Update](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.Update/) library it might give you ClickOnce stuff for updates, but first install you've got to do using another too.

Comment: hmm this looks interesting...ill check it out

Answer (score 0):

Can you execute a process during the ClickOnce install? You might be able to write the service using [Topshelf](http://code.google.com/p/topshelf/) and then execute MyService.exe /install from ClickOnce.