# What installer options do I have for bundling a windows service along with a WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-services, windows-installer

I've already looked at [C#: Making an Installer that installs both a WPF application (ClickOnce) and a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765457/c-making-an-installer-that-installs-both-a-wpf-application-clickonce-and-a-w) but that never answered my question. I have a similar set up: a WPF application and a Windows Service. I'd like one installer that installs the Windows Service first, then installs the WPF application. Also, it has to be able to open firewall exceptions as well.

Anybody have any experience with any products that can do this? I've got the feeling that InstallShield Premier can do this but I'd prefer not having to spend $500 or so for a license.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at WIX?  It's an open source tool for building MSI setups.  It's pretty well supported.  I haven't used it to do what you are asking, but a quick search did reveal a firewall settings extension for WIX: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/05/17/new-wix-feature-firewall-extension/

Comment: No idea why people use anything else than WIX. Yes, it needs more work - but hey, it gives you CONTROL and that according to the requireents of windows (contrary to Nullsoft, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System(NSIS)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)?

A little while ago, I decided to take a little utility I wrote and make redistributable<sup>1</sup>. I looked at a whole bunch of standard installer options (i.e. VS IDE vs. different flavors of InstallShield) and one thing I didn't like is that they could all do trivial things, but if you needed something just a tad more complicated, the best option was non-free InstallShield or you are out of luck.

Then I came across NSIS. From my initial impression, it looks to be a full blown installer builder. It supports most features, even complicated ones and it is open source. Even for things that the product itself doesn't support, there's a strong community of other developers that post their own scripts and add-ons.

It is probably not as easy to use as InstallShield (I remember IS had visual and very friendly IDE). This one is more scripted, so you need to understand their language. But it's not difficult, I was able to ramp up and create and install package within one day.

<sup>1-If you wish to see what NSIS script looks like, you can follow GitHub link in my profile. The project is called "Droppy"</sup>