# Simple installation of WindowsService

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm having difficulty implementing a WindowsService with C# Express. What I want is to write a class that separates the installation logic from the service, er, service. To make this worthwhile I am looking to remove the class deriving from installer and be left with just the service itself, as I thought http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx might describe. All these fancy install and packaging wizards are absent from my Express edn so I must use only .NET classes.

I'm considering `ManagedInstallerClass` and `AssemblyInstaller` and **_*not*_** installutil, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ManagedInstallerClass`.

The answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144019/self-install-windows-service-in-net-c) question are excellent. Please check [Self install windows service in .NET c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144019/self-install-windows-service-in-net-c) and the code midpage here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2009/01/04/self-installing-windows-service.aspx (this example uses `AssemblyInstaller`).

Comment: If you want to create a self install windows service you can also look to http://topshelf-project.com/.