# Trying to install Window Service on Production Server which does not have VS 2015 installed

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I developed a Window Service which is running successfully(tested using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015) on my local machine because I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. My machine is a development Server.

After successfully tested it on my machine, I tried to install the same process using installutil.exe.But, I think, this exe is not present on my Window Production server because VS 2015 is not installed on production server? I have IIS installed and my website is deployed there and working fine. I found that there is no Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015 on production server

Do I need any other way to install Window Server on my Production Server?

Answer (score 0):

InstallUtil is a developer tool, so it is not present on most machines without Visual Studio. Besides creating a full blown MSI installer, you can [implement a self-install that behaves like installutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144019/self-install-windows-service-in-net-c-sharp). An alternative to implementing this yourself is to build your service using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) because it includes this self-install functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to install the service on remote machine from localhost?

Comment: @Pankaj Not easily, but that's a completely different question. InstallUtil does't do that and I doubt Topsehlf does either. If you implement the self-install described, you could probably do a remote install with psexec.

Comment: @Pankajm, you can install service on remote machine from localhost.
So, you can use **sc** for it or use **WMI**, [see](http://www.gkspk.com/view/programming/working-with-windows-services-using-csharp-and-wmi/)