# Windows Service Deployment

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-services

I am currently deploying my windows services manually on the server.

One time Steps:

1. Install Location on server hosting windows server -> `D:\InstallDir`
2. Copied windows Service related files into this folder
3. Created a batch file to Install Windows Service (`InstallUtil.Exe`) and another batch file to uninstall windows service and copied in the install folder
4. Installed windows service using the install batch file

Here are the steps I perform to upgrade:

1. Take backup of existing Install folder (to use in case I need to rollback to prev version)
2. Run uninstall batch file to uninstall the windows service (`InstallUtil /u`)
3. Copy new DLLs from a location on build server into Install Folder (on server hosting windows services)
4. Run install batch file to Install the windows service (`InstallUtil WIndowsService.Exe`)

I would like to automate upgrade steps; can you suggest deployment strategy in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a walk through for setting up a Setup Project for a Windows Service.  I've used it and it's simple to use and simple to create.  It creates a standard .msi file to install from. Since it's a standard Setup project creating a standard msi, you can set it to automatically uninstall previous versions, etc.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421

Comment: the page isn't there any more

Answer (score 2):

You can use an installer like [`Inno-setup`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), check this related question using inno-setup
[`Inno Setup for Windows service`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449994/inno-setup-for-windows-service).