# Best practice deploying windows service

Tags: deployment, windows-services, continuous-integration

I'm looking for best practice in continuous delivery of windows services.

Currently we hava a set of powershell scripts that unintall, reboot, install updates but error handling is tricky. We are reviewing System center but are there any other options available for deploying a windows service?

Answer (score 2):

We've been using Presto since Dec 2011, and have done over 1,000 deployments. Most of what we deploy are Windows services.

What's nice is that we set up our apps and servers in Presto, then we can repeatedly deploy, to any server (or multiple servers at once), by just hitting a button. Presto will copy our official release binaries, update all of the items in our app config files, create and start the service, etc...

So, if you have an application that has 30 manual steps to deploying it, you can enter these steps in Presto, then it's done automatically for you after that.

It's worth a look: http://presto.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your most basic and generally accepted best option comes from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743064/windows-service-deployment), which basically links to a [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421) on creating an installer for the windows service.