# How do I distribute a Windows service that depends on a class library?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

I have a Visual Studio solution.  This solutions contains two projects.  The first is a class library with all methods that communicate with sql server db.  The second is a windows service project will run every 30 minutes.

How do I distribute this setup in one package?

I have tried:

> 1-adding the class library as a reference to windows service. 
>   2-create a setup project and adding the windows service in the application folder.
>   3-adding the windows service and the class library to the application folder.

this is a screenshot [image: screenshot] for the error.

I think this error because the class library couldn't reach the SQL db.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Service Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743064/windows-service-deployment)

Comment: @Ignasi93 No, this answer to install a windows service but my question is about packaging windows service with the class library using setup project in visual studio

Answer (score -2):

You are looking to deploy a windows service that is dependent on a DLL.

"deploy" is the standard for what you're calling "distribute".  You understand the underlying concept but just realize that the standard is called "deploy".

There are details to do this here...

[Windows Service Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743064/windows-service-deployment)