# Install windows service without using InstallUtil or Setup Installation

Tags: windows, windows-services

I would like to send a windows service program to our client that does not have InstallUtil (no rights to distribute) and this one will be multiple installations in the same machine.

I found something at this point: [Inno Setup for Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449994/inno-setup-for-windows-service)

But I am not clear how to:

- add the InnoSetup script and where to add this script?
- For the if and else: System.Environment.UserInteractive? if a service is not installed, then it will be going inside this if?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have provided a step-by-step solution for how to add command-line install/uninstall to your Windows service using C#.  This solution lets you avoid requiring the use of `InstallUtil`.

[How to make a .NET Windows Service start right after the installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621)

Comment: THis works great! Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea why Console.Writeline("ALALA") does not print to the screen? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an installer to your service setup project, and a custom action. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) will get you started.