# How to install windows service using Inno Setup?

Tags: c#, windows-services, inno-setup

In VS2010 I have solution with windows service project and some other 'helper' projects. So in my debug folder there is an windows service application and couple of dlls.

I can install windows service by running application with parameter, so in Inno Setup I just do:

```
Filename: {app}\MyService.exe; Parameters: "--install"; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: skipifdoesntexist; StatusMsg: "MyService is being installed. Please wait..."
```

My question in: It is necessary to pack all files from Release folder to my Setup file? I mean, in my Release folder are: DLLs from my other projects in app solution, Program Debug Database (.pdb) files, and XML Configuration file..

What files should be packed in my Setup.exe file?

Comment: Why don't you tell Inno to install the service. It knows how to do it. You don't want to install .pdb file. You want to install config file if the service depends on it.

Comment: @ David H: He wants to install service from the application as mentioned here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449994/inno-setup-for-windows-service

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Inno doesn't know anything about services itself, but can call out to the SCM API or a normal [Run] entry as Marshall is trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the `*.exe` files.
`*.pbd` and other are not needed there.

Only DLLs if nedded by your main project (service).

Comment: Thanks, I was curious why the other files are in Release folder. btw. how about xml file ?

Comment: the pdbs will be therte if you changed the project options to create symbolic debug info in release mode. The XML files could be anything, but if they're app config, it depends how your app handles them not existing/default options.