# How to create a setup project for a application with Windows Service using inno setup compiler

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-project

I am creating a setup project for my application in vs12, my application has a windows form and a windows service, how can I add a service in installer using inno setup Compiler? or any other setup creator?
I used  Install shield limited version before but i am unable to create app folder in program data with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inno Setup for Windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449994/inno-setup-for-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a Custom Action in your Setup Project and then you install the User Service silently by modifying registries. There are some example that you can find on the internet. One of the good examples i have found from Code Project site.

[Install Windows Service using Custom Actions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26091/Install-Windows-Service-using-Custom-Actions)