# What launches the installation of a Windows Service Installer?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a Service using [Microsoft's walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#BK_AddInstallers).

It works. But I don't understand how. The `Main()` method doesn't seem to call the `ProjectInstaller` constructor (which looks like what installs the service). In fact, `ProjectInstaller` isn't referenced anywhere in the solution (I checked using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>).

So how is it executed?

**EDIT**

I'm not using **installutil**. `Program`'s `Main()` calls `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);`.

Comment: I suspect `installutil.exe` looks for it

Comment: @MickyD I'm not using installutil. `Program`'s `Main()` calls `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);`.

Comment: Well you should be using installutil.  How do you expect to install the service otherwise?

Comment: @MickyD See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449994/inno-setup-for-windows-service/1450051#1450051 . I'm using it because it's way simpler.

Comment: installutil.exe is shipped with .NET.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Program which you use to install that service (`installutil.exe`) inspects your assembly and runs installers. As stated in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool):

> Installutil.exe uses reflection to inspect the specified assemblies
>   and to find all Installer types that have the
>   System.ComponentModel.RunInstallerAttribute attribute set to true.
>
> The
>   tool then executes either the Installer.Install or the
>   Installer.Uninstall method on each instance of the Installer type.
>   Installutil.exe performs installation in a transactional manner; that
>   is, if one of the assemblies fails to install, it rolls back the
>   installations of all other assemblies. Uninstall is not transactional.

Update: You said you do not use `installutil` and instead using `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper`. Reading documentation of this class:

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code.
>
> Handles the functionality of the Installutil.exe (Installer Tool).

So first you should not be using it, and second - it does the same as `installutil` (so related to this question - uses reflection to inspect your assembly and run installers). I suppose that `installutil` tool actually just calls this method. Note that you have to pass path to your assembly in `args` of `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper`, that's how it knows which assembly to inspect with reflection and run installer for.

Comment: I'm not using installutil. `Program`'s `Main()` calls `ServiceBase.Run(services);`.

Comment: @ispiro and how do you install your service then? Tutorial you linked uses `installutil` for that.

Comment: Sorry, wrong method: `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);` is what I meant.

Comment: So you're saying that when I call it, it finds `ProjectInstaller` by it being in the assembly, and then runs it?

Comment: `Note that you have to pass path to your assembly` - correct. That's what I'm doing. If not it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes it finds `ProjectInstaller` in the assembly which path you pass to it. In the example you linked, they do: `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });`. So it loads assembly you passed (your current assembly actually), finds installer, then runs it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!