# Setup project template for vs2012?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, setup-project

I have a wpf application which needs to generate an installer file. The IDE for this project is vs2012. I found there was no setup project template at all in vs2012. I googled the solution and I found template below which was for vs2013.
[enter link description here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Is there any setup solution for vs2012?

Comment: Nope. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-

Comment: @PeterRitchie so you meant there was no solution for vs2012? is there any idea for generating installer package for a winform project which is developed in vs2012?

Comment: I'd suggest wix http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: [Visual Studio setup projects (vdproj) will not ship with future versions of VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with clickonce solution to deploy your application. It is quite easy to use clickonce. Just google this.

If you want to generate the installer using setup project than you will definitely require the Setup and Deployment template in Visual studio but unfortunately Microsoft has removed the Setup project template from VS2012.

In this case you can go with WIX which is a free open source alternative, far more functional, but tricky to set up.

See the link for more details.
[VS2013 Windows Service - How to make installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938128/vs2013-windows-service-how-to-make-installer)

Comment: It seems to be a solution for making installer for windows service. Does it work for common winform application?