# Install windows service without InstallUtil.exe

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-services, installation

I'm trying to deploy a windows service but not quite sure how to do it right. I built it as a console app to start with, I've now turned it into a windows service project and just call my class from the OnStart method in the service.

I now need to install this on a server which doesn't have Visual Studio on it, which if I've understood it correctly means I can't use the InstallUtil.exe and have to create an installer class instead. Is this correct?

I did have a look at a previous question, [Install a .NET windows service without InstallUtil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255056/install-a-net-windows-service-without-installutil-exe), but I just want to make sure I've understood it correctly.

If I create the class that question's accepted answer links to, what is the next step? Upload MyService.exe and MyService.exe.config to the server, double click the exe file and Bob's my uncle?

The service will only ever be installed on one server.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255056/install-a-net-windows-service-without-installutil-exe

Comment: @AZ Yes, I know, I thought it would be fine to ask the question anyway as I'm referring to the previous question and mine's slightly different in that it's not a .net service (it doesn't have any interface) so wanted to make sure the same answers would apply.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `InstallUtil.exe` tool is simply a wrapper around some reflection calls against the installer component(s) in your service.  As such, it really doesn't do much but exercise the functionality these installer components provide.  Marc Gravell's solution simply provides a means to do this from the command line so that you no longer have to rely on having `InstallUtil.exe` on the target machine.

Here's my step-by-step that based on Marc Gravell's solution.

[How to make a .NET Windows Service start right after the installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621)

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost there with this. I get a security exception saying 'The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security'. I'm guessing this might have to do with the account it's running under as @ho is talking about in his comment. I've set it to LocalService, but I'll change that and try again. By the way, tiny spelling mistake in your code, for the InstallService() it says 'IDictionary state = new Hasttable();' rather than Hashtable.

Comment: No probs. Right, I've tried with all the different accounts, all except User gives the same exception, and for User I have to enter username and password. Which username and password should that be? For the user I'm logging in to the server with?

Comment: I managed to install it! I use the LocalSystem account, had to run as administrator when opening the command prompt for it to work. Now I need to figure out why the service is stopping as soon as it starts, but that's another question. :) Thanks!

Comment: In the constructor of your Windows service class (or in the `OnStart()` event handler), put a call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`.  When you start your service, you'll be prompted to enter a debug session.  You can debug from there.  I think you have to have admin rights on your machine for this to work, though.

Answer (score 70):

I know it is a very old question, but better update it with new information.

You can install service by using [sc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) command:

**InstallService.bat:**

```
@echo OFF
echo Stopping old service version...
net stop "[YOUR SERVICE NAME]"
echo Uninstalling old service version...
sc delete "[YOUR SERVICE NAME]"

echo Installing service...
rem DO NOT remove the space after "binpath="!
sc create "[YOUR SERVICE NAME]" binpath= "[PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVICE_EXE]" start= auto
echo Starting server complete
pause
```

With SC, you can do a lot more things as well: uninstalling the old service (if you already installed it before), checking if service with same name exists... even set your service to autostart.

One of many references: [creating a service with sc.exe; how to pass in context parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)

I have done by both this way & `InstallUtil`. Personally I feel that using SC is cleaner and better for your health.

Comment: This is super easy and should be upvoted way more than the other methods.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to install a windows service

Comment: I agree, this is totally the easiest solution and should be upvoted FAR more than the other UBER COMPLEX solutions!  Good stuff!

Comment: Agree, this should be the solution. No installer needed and SC is included in Windows Server already.

Comment: Update 2022: _rem DO NOT remove the space after "binpath="!_ doesn't seem to apply anymore under Windows 10.

Answer (score 34):

You can still use installutil without visual studio, it is included with the .net framework

On your server, open a command prompt as administrator then:

```
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.version (insert your version)

installutil "C:\Program Files\YourWindowsService\YourWindowsService.exe" (insert your service name/location)
```

To uninstall:

```
installutil /u "C:\Program Files\YourWindowsService\YourWindowsService.exe" (insert your service name/location)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a base service class (ServiceBase subclass) that can be subclassed to build a windows service that can be easily installed from the command line, without installutil.exe. This solution is derived from [How to make a .NET Windows Service start right after the installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621), adding some code to get the service Type using the calling StackFrame

```
public abstract class InstallableServiceBase:ServiceBase
{

    /// <summary>
    /// returns Type of the calling service (subclass of InstallableServiceBase)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static Type getMyType()
    {
        Type t = typeof(InstallableServiceBase);
        MethodBase ret = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
        Type retType = null;
        try
        {
            StackFrame[] frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
            foreach (StackFrame x in frames)
            {
                ret = x.GetMethod();

                Type t1 = ret.DeclaringType;

                if (t1 != null && !t1.Equals(t) &&   !t1.IsSubclassOf(t))
                {


                    break;
                }
                retType = t1;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return retType;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// returns AssemblyInstaller for the calling service (subclass of InstallableServiceBase)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static AssemblyInstaller GetInstaller()
    {
        Type t = getMyType();
        AssemblyInstaller installer = new AssemblyInstaller(
            t.Assembly, null);
        installer.UseNewContext = true;
        return installer;
    }

    private bool IsInstalled()
    {
        using (ServiceController controller =
            new ServiceController(this.ServiceName))
        {
            try
            {
                ServiceControllerStatus status = controller.Status;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private bool IsRunning()
    {
        using (ServiceController controller =
            new ServiceController(this.ServiceName))
        {
            if (!this.IsInstalled()) return false;
            return (controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// protected method to be called by a public method within the real service
    /// ie: in the real service
    ///    new internal  void InstallService()
    ///    {
    ///        base.InstallService();
    ///    }
    /// </summary>
    protected void InstallService()
    {
        if (this.IsInstalled()) return;

        try
        {
            using (AssemblyInstaller installer = GetInstaller())
            {

                IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
                try
                {
                    installer.Install(state);
                    installer.Commit(state);
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        installer.Rollback(state);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// protected method to be called by a public method within the real service
    /// ie: in the real service
    ///    new internal  void UninstallService()
    ///    {
    ///        base.UninstallService();
    ///    }
    /// </summary>
    protected void UninstallService()
    {
        if (!this.IsInstalled()) return;

        if (this.IsRunning()) {
            this.StopService();
        }
        try
        {
            using (AssemblyInstaller installer = GetInstaller())
            {
                IDictionary state = new Hashtable();
                try
                {
                    installer.Uninstall(state);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void StartService()
    {
        if (!this.IsInstalled()) return;

        using (ServiceController controller =
            new ServiceController(this.ServiceName))
        {
            try
            {
                if (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    controller.Start();
                    controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running,
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private void StopService()
    {
        if (!this.IsInstalled()) return;
        using (ServiceController controller =
            new ServiceController(this.ServiceName))
        {
            try
            {
                if (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                {
                    controller.Stop();
                    controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped,
                         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do is to implement two public/internal methods in your real service:

```
    new internal  void InstallService()
    {
        base.InstallService();
    }
    new internal void UninstallService()
    {
        base.UninstallService();
    }
```

and then call them when you want to install the service:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            MyService s1 = new MyService();
            if (args.Length == 1)
            {
                switch (args[0])
                {
                    case "-install":
                        s1.InstallService();

                        break;
                    case "-uninstall":

                        s1.UninstallService();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }


        }
        else {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(MyService);            
        }

    }
```

Comment: is this how `sysmon -i/-u` does it too?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just create a setup project? It's really easy.

1. Add a service installer to the service (you do it on the seemingly useless service "design" surface)
2. Create a setup project and add the Service output to the setup app folder
3. Most importantly add the Service project output to all the custom actions

Voila, and you're done.

See here for more:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx

There is also a way to prompt the user for credentials (or supply your own).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this if I can't get the other suggestions to work. Not sure what credentials you mean?

Comment: With credentials he means the account which the service runs under.

Comment: @ho Which account should the service run under? Basically the service watches some folders for new files, uploads files to a database if there's new files then moves the files to a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) is an OSS project which was started after this question was answered and it makes Windows service much, MUCH easier.I highly recommend looking into it.

http://topshelf-project.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not double click, you run it with the correct command line parameters, so type something like `MyService -i` and then `MyService -u` to uninstall it`.

You could otherwise use sc.exe to install and uninstall it (or copy along InstallUtil.exe).

Answer (score 0):

This Problem is due to Security, Better open Developer Command prompt for VS 2012 in RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR and install your Service, it fix your problem surely.