# Run Java application at Windows startup

Tags: java, windows, startup

I have a JAR file containing a Java application. How can I make it start with Windows, without needing user interaction?

Comment: See also [How to create a windows service from java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app)

Answer (score 40):

Create a .bat file and put this inside:

`javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\Path\to\jarfile\TheJar.jar`

Then put the .bat file into the windows startup folder.

> One more thing: There's a difference between using **java** and **javaw**. While **java** is better when you are debugging an application, the application prints text or something like that, **javaw** is better when you don't need that. Why? Because **java** runs java program using a console that shows all that application prints (println's, exception stacktraces and so on) while **javaw** doesn't run on console.

Comment: anyother way than keeping it inside start up folder

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen When would it happend otherwise?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 services are run at boot time (if configured so).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ah, sorry.

Answer (score 24):

it's simple as you have to put shortcut in

**Windows 7**
`C:\users\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`(Admin)  or `User home directory(%userProfile%)`

**Windows 10 :**
In Run   `shell:startup`

in it's property -> shortcut -> target - > `java.exe -jar D:\..\runJar.jar`

**NOTE: This will run only after you login**

---

**With Admin Right**

`sc create serviceName binpath= "java.exe -jar D:\..\runJar.jar"` Will create windows service

if you get **timeout** use `cmd /c D:\JAVA7~1\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe -jar d:\jenkins\jenkins.war` but even with this you'll get timeout but in background java.exe will be started. Check in task manager

---

In some restricted environment as I was in corporate environment

**ERROR:**

`The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

In this case

`cmd /c D:\JAVA7~1\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe -jar d:\jenkins\jenkins.war`

This will give you an error if you run manually but will run in background.

**NOTE: This will run at windows logon start-up(before sign-in, Based on service '`Startup Type`')**

[Detailed explanation of creating windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)

---

**Regedit**

**Note: Edit Advanced User only**

**To Run for Current User Only**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS/CURRENT_VERSION/RUN
```

**To Run for All Users**

```
hkey_local_machine/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/WINDOWS/CURRENT_VERSION/RUN
```

Create a String with Name and Path using above command

Comment: `sc create` wouldn't work  as `java.exe` isn't implement `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 13):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app) might suit your needs. Setup your java application to run as a windows service and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open 'Run' (Windows-Key+`R`)
2. Write `regedit`
3. Go to `HKey local machine` -> `Software` -> `Microsoft` -> `Windows` -> `Current version` -> `run`
4. Click on it and in the other panel right-click on nothing and choose
   `Add` -> `String value`
5. Name it `java`
6. Double-click it and put it's value as follows:
   `javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\Path\to\jarfile\TheJar.jar`

Comment: does it needs the apostrophes at the begining and at the end? or quotes? or nothing?

Comment: No - You can leave it empty if the directory has no spaces

Comment: Just I was thinking about the initial aphostrophe in your answer, i mean: --> 'javaw...

Comment: is there any way we can see std logs after this? in Linux by systemd units u can always try and look at the logs by running journalctl, so is there any alternative to that with this method?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it programmatically from Java you can write directly into Windows registry startup folder.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) is link how to write into Windows registry programmatically.

when you have implemented function to work with registry than what you need is just run this code

```
String value = "\"javaw -jar " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\myJar.jar\"";
WinRegistry.writeStringValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "myJar autorun key", value);
```

where value for key need to be command what runs your application like java -jar myJar.jar

to remove it from autorun you simply

```
WinRegistry.deleteValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "myJar autorun key");
```

**UPDATE**

```
Replace WinRegistry.writeStringValue with WinRegistry.setStringValue recent version of java 1.8.x
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to create service from any executable use `srvany.exe` from [Windows
Resource Kits 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17657) (take attention to spaces after `=`)::

```
cmd> sc create NAME binPath= "c:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe" ^
   type= own start= auto error= normal DisplayName= "NAME for services.msc"
```

Then pass what `srvany.exe` wrapper will do:

```
cmd> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NAME\Parameters" ^
     /v "Application" ^
     /d "\"c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe\" -cp c:\home\devel\service Main"
```

Above you see quoting syntax for spaces. Next start service with:

```
cmd> sc start NAME
```

If you make error recheck your settings with:

```
cmd> reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NAME" /s
```

and remove service:

```
cmd> sc delete NAME
```

and make steps again.

Visit GUI `services.msc` and check with `procexp.exe` service actually start.

See also:  [creating a service with sc.exe; how to pass in context parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)

**NOTE** All involved instruments is **official Microsoft**!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use "winsw" - http://kenai.com/projects/winsw - which was written for Glassfish v3 but works well with Java programs in general.

Require .NET runtime installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not ready to do the config yourself or if you want the same functionality on multile computers, then you can use [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). You can package jars to be installed on Windows and set params that will run your program on startup