# Run Java application and load config file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a JAR file that I set to run when Windows starts per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup) but I have a .cfg file I need to load. Is there an argument I can add to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it right into your code:

```
File configFile = new File("path/to/file.cfg");
```

or get from console, for example  from first argument of your programm:

```
File configFile = new File(args[0]);
```