# how to re-run java application when the pc restarts?

Tags: java, jvm

I am currently developing a chat application based on the server and client. is it possible to make the application run by it self when the pc restarts. in my case I want the client to re-connect to the server once the pc restarts. is there a way of making a java application starts by it self?

is it possible to do it from the application it self rather then the cmd

Comment: What OS is the PC running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Java application at Windows startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup)

Comment: is there anything specific about why it needs to be "re-run" rather than simply run on start up?

Comment: Windows 7 Operating system

Comment: yeah, I want the client to re-connect to the server by it self, instead of having them to reconnect to me

Comment: but, I want it to be done from the application it self, so I can update the state wheather the client is online or offline

Comment: You should put it in the startup folder or registry... And you would need to make sure your socket is alive if not reconnect in a while loop