# Java autoconfigure startup execution at first launch

Tags: java, startup

I'm trying to program something that, at first execution, in any OS could, set itself at startup OS programs list.

There are any library that do that? Or I should search how to do that in each OS?

I want to do an unique file, so I don't want to use scripts and anything.

Comment: You'll have to investigate for each OS. And you might not be allowed to do so on some system.

Comment: @Gaël, with user privileges, I found in linux the ~/.profile and in windows the register keys. Do you mean for the registry keys may I must be the admin?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I don't found any API for solve that.

In Unix system modifying (I think it could work in MAC, but not verified)

~/.profile     <- User Privileges

/etc/profile   <- With admin privileges

For Windows you can modify directly the key register

[Run Java application at Windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup)

Or try to copy the program to the startup folder