# How to get a Jar file from it's own project and write it to a Windows folder

Tags: java, jar

I am looking to write a jar filer to a folder in the computer, that is located at the Jar file itself.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJcwi.png)

Basically what I want, is to make the program start everytime that windows will run, using the "Startup" folder.

I want that when I start "Guic" Jar file, it will write the Jar file "Surprize" to the windows folder "Startup".

I am sorry if this is not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to run a java application every time your computer runs. I haven't done it before and don't have much time right now to search it in-depth, but i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup) will help you. If I am wrong about and I haven't get that right, please let me know. Also, if the answer I provided you is not enough inform me so I can try it on my own and get back to you.