# run console app after boot automatically

Tags: java, linux, raspbian

I made small java app for logging users by ID. It reads input using **System.in.read()** in loop and on Enter key it saves readed string to log file with actual date and time as a new line (it´s designed for use with RFID reader). Each readed symbol is also printed to stdout prefixed with "Readed: "

App works fine when is started by command **java -jar app.jar**.

I want to start this app automatically after system boot so I add start script into **/etc/init.d/**

And there is a problem. App is started, but it runs on background. When I redirect stdout to file via **java -jar app.jar >> log.txt** in start script, after reboot and open log file there are many lines with string "Readed: " folowed by non-ascii character, and lines count is growing by a thousands every minute.

I am not able to redirect standard input into this app.

Is there any possibility how to automatically run command in default console(with standard input/output from/to console) when system boots in command-line mode (without GUI)?

I very appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: These answers should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup

Comment: use log4j, logging api, so that it write everything to log. You do not need to worry about the standard out.

Comment: try adding the command to the `.profile` file - will be executed when you login

Comment: Maybe this questions is better suited for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or even [Super User](https://superuser.com/)