# Apache, MySQL, and FTP 'Detected With Wrong Path' using XAMPP on Win7

Tags: mysql, apache, ftp, xampp

I'm having the following issues when trying to access XAMPP on my Win7. They are configured to start automatically when the OS is loaded. and the following message are what I see

> 6:25:17 AM  [apache]  Apache Service Detected With Wrong Path
>   6:25:17 AM  [apache]  Uninstall the service manually first
>   6:25:17 AM  [mysql]   MySQL Service Detected With Wrong Path
>   6:25:17 AM  [mysql]   Uninstall the service manually first
>   6:25:17 AM  [filezilla]   FileZilla Service Detected With wrong Path
>   6:25:17 AM  [filezilla]   Uninstall the service manually first

And the Apache error log is as follows:

> [Sun Aug 19 06:24:16.719046 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 1516:tid 384] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache] 
>   [Sun Aug 19 06:24:20.493262 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1516:tid 384] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Sun Aug 19 06:24:20.494262 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1516:tid 384] AH00456: Server built: May 13 2012 14:10:15
>   [Sun Aug 19 06:24:20.494262 2012] [core:notice] [pid 1516:tid 384] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>   [Sun Aug 19 06:24:20.496262 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1516:tid 384] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 324
>   [Sun Aug 19 06:24:22.116354 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 324:tid 288] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>   [Sun Aug 19 06:24:22.174358 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 324:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

And the MySQL error log

> 120819  6:24:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 
>   120819  6:24:19 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>   120819  6:24:19 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>   120819  6:24:19 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   120819  6:24:19 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>   120819  6:24:19 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   120819  6:24:19 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   120819  6:24:21  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
>   120819  6:24:22 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 4011253
>   120819  6:24:22 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
>   120819  6:24:22 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
>   120819  6:24:22 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
>   120819  6:24:27 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   120819  6:24:27 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
>   Version: '5.5.25a'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Btw, editing is kind of hard here, having to do <br /> at every line

Answer (score 9):

What that error message is indicating is that you have a MySQL Windows Service installed that is not part of the current XAMPP you are using (it detects the services by name then validates the service path). You indicated that you uninstalled a previous external MySQL installation. If this is the only other installation you are aware of on your system, it may not have automatically removed the service from Windows Services when it uninstalled.

If this is the case, you can do the following:

1. Open a command prompt (Start > Run > cmd) run as administrator
2. Type the following:

   ```
   Code: Select all
   sc delete mysql
   ```

   and hit return. (Note: this requires admin privileges.)

If the second step completes successfully, you should be able to reopen the control panel and see what it then says. If all is well, you can install the MySQL Window Service for the XAMPP MySQL by clicking the red 'X' in the control panel that should be next to MySQL if all went well.

Comment: Formatting of code in numbered lists in Markdown is tricky. I've tweaked it here. Please have a look at it and edit if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Just uncheck and check button in Module Services column. It will automatically delete old service and start new service with new path. It happens when you delete xampp folder directly without stopping services.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended to supplement the one from Sarang.  I just want to make clear, because it wasn't obvious to me, that it's possible to have an existing installation of MySQL and one tied to XAMPP running simultaneously. Here's how, along the same lines as Sarang's answer but hopefully with detail that provides extra useful guidance:

1. Run XAMPP Control Panel as administrator
2. Click MySQL/Config and change port to 3307 in two places
3. Stop MySQL service for existing installation
4. Run cmd.exe as administrator.  Type "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqladmin"-u root -p shutdown. This will stop service for existing installation of MySQL
5. Back in XAMPP Control Panel, click on green check-mark next to MySQL: this will delete service for existing installation of MySQL
6. Click XAMPP Control Panel/Config and configure as below

[image]

6. Click Service and Port Settings and change port for MySQL to 3307 (I'm not sure if this is really necessary)
7. Quit XAMPP run again as administrator.  This will start up Apache and MySql services
8. Run cmd.exe as administrator.  Type "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --install.  This will reinstall service for existing installation of MySQL
9. Open up Window Services.  Start service for existing installation of MySQL

Comment: It says -u is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get <s>it to work</s> around this by running as administrator.

Comment: This worked for me as well. This might be more of an issue on centrally-managed workstations as they tend to be more restrictive. I have Win7 64b at home and do not need to run as administrator to install the services, but at work I do.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you had installed apache seperately apart from the xampp apache.....
no worries.....
try the below steps it will resolve your issue

open cmd > run as administrator type the following commands

```
httpd -k shutdown
httpd -k stop
httpd -k uninstall
```

or
open powershell> run as administrator type the following commands

```
.\httpd -k shutdown
.\httpd -k stop
.\httpd -k uninstall
```

or

```
win + R
type services.msc
then find Apache24 or httpd
now open cmd > run as administrator
type sc delete "<your services name from the list for apache>"
```

thanks to the sources and contributors :)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post, it is very similar and it helped me fix my problems (delete previous installations of apache and mysql)

[XAMPP on Windows - Apache not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794829/xampp-on-windows-apache-not-starting)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Command Prompt** and Open it as a **Administrator**

*just type*

```
sc delete MySQL
```

*and then*

```
sc delete Apache2.4
```

Close the XAMPP and open it again.