# Error installing Apache with xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I recently manually installed and configured PHP, Apache, MySql, and phpmyadmin following a youtube tutitorial. It seemed like everything was working fine, but today when I finished a script for a registration form, I was getting an error statement that said "Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect(). So I decided to uninstall PHP, Apache, Mysql, and phpmyadmin, and try xampp. Now on xampp's control panel I am getting this error and I am completely lost on what to do. Any insight/helpp would be much appreciated...

```
    9:31:53 PM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
    9:31:53 PM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
    9:31:53 PM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
    9:31:53 PM  [Apache]    Found Path: "c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
    9:31:53 PM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP on Windows - Apache not starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794829/xampp-on-windows-apache-not-starting)

Comment: I have completely uninstalled xampp from my computer and tried reinstalling it and I am getting the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute `netstat -nlpt` command.And figure out mysql process .Kill it and start your wampp.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do not know how to execute this command? Do I type that in on the command prompt?

Comment: I would also like to add that the path Xampp is saying it has found was deleted. So I do not know how Xampp is still saying it has "found" this.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I ended up uninstalling this and installing WAMP and WAMP is up and running! But thanks to everyone for helping me along the way!