# I already deleted a folder, but Xampp says it still exists and is the "found path"

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Before I installed Xampp, I had manually configured php, phpmyadmin, apache, and mysql on my computer using a youtube tutitorial. However after writing a few login scripts for my website in php I was getting alot of errors with mysql, so I decided to uninstall/delete everything and try using xampp. Now on the control panel in xampp, I am getting this error message:

```
    Apache Service detected with wrong path
    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
    Found Path: "c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

I deleted this folder that xampp is saying it has found? I have no idea why it is saying it has found this or what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing Apache with xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137819/error-installing-apache-with-xampp)

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, I am still learning a lot. How do I check the $PATH? Can I do this if I am using Windows rather than Linux?

Comment: Yes, https://www.google.com/#q=edit+windows+path