# How to check service startup type from batch script? (in windows 7)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I need to start a service from batch file (using `sc start XXX`), but ONLY if it is configured with an automatic start up type.

I read the instructions of `sc /?` and I tried calling first to `sc qc XXX` command in order to query for it's configuration and then use findstr on the result, but I got the following error after `sc qc XXX` command:

```
[SC] QueryServiceConfig FAILED 122:

The data area passed to a system call is too small.

[SC] GetServiceConfig needs 718 bytes
```

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Which is odd, because I am able to call `sc config XXX` and stop/start it from command line.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: PowerShell is probably better suited for this kind of things.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it in standard shell?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I just figured it out.

First, I must apologize , since the original error was actually:

```
[SC] QueryServiceConfig FAILED 122:

The data area passed to a system call is too small.

[SC] GetServiceConfig needs 718 bytes
```

and not

```
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:
```

as I first said.

Apparently, I had to explicitly add a buffer size to my service :
sc qc XXX **1000**

After doing that, i noticed that BINARY_PATH_NAME field was extremely long for XXX, so I guess that default memory allocation was not enough.

Now, since I basically owe StackOverflow my career, I will post my full code :)

```
rem start a service, but only if it is configured as automatic, and only if it isn't running already
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc qc %xxx% 1000^| findstr "START_TYPE"') do (
    if /I "%%H" EQU "AUTO_START" (
        rem check if service is stopped
        for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query %xxx% ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
            if /I "%%H" EQU "STOPPED" (
                echo net start %xxx%
                net start %xxx%
            ) else (
                echo %xxx% is already running
            )
        )
    ) else (
        echo Skipping %xxx% since it's not defined as automatic start
    )
)
```

Comment: Please edit your original question to have the correct error message, which will help others facing this issue to find this question.