# windows service update exe options without remove / reinstall

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-services, powershell-4.0

I've a windows service installed and working fine with a path to exe :

> c:\myproject\mybinary.exe -home d:\home - generateFiles false

I want to add another option : `-option optionValue`

Since I have around 200 different services, installed in a 15 different servers, it is complicated to uninstall and reinstall with the new option.

Is there somehow to add the new option without any change to the service binary?

Comment: Does the binary actually provide this option, or do you need to implement the option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "Name='My Service'" `
    | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Change `
    -ArgumentList @($null,$null,$null,$null,$null, `
    "c:\myproject\mybinary.exe -home d:\home -generateFiles false -option optionValue")
```

Or:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\My Service" `
    -Name ImagePath -Value "c:\myproject\mybinary.exe -home d:\home -generateFiles false -option optionValue"
```

You would need to restart service afterwards: `Restart-Service "My Service"`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190480/modifying-the-path-to-executable-of-a-windows-service).