# Fix mongod install via command line

Tags: mongodb

After installing mongodb on windows, I set up the necessary folders but made a typing mistake when doing the following command:

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mondodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --rest --install
```

the folder is named `mongodb` but i named it `mondodb` by accident and can't seem to overwrite that, so when I start mongodb by doing `net start mongodb` I get an error in my log saying `C:\mondodb\data\db not found`

I tried redoing it like so `mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --rest --install` but it's not working.

how can I redo the mongod thingy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different things you could try:

- Go into the registry and change the service path: [Modifying the "Path to executable" of a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190480/modifying-the-path-to-executable-of-a-windows-service).  After you modify it, you can go into Services.msc, right-click on the service, go to Properties, then Look at the `Path to executable:` and make sure that it points to mongodb rather than mondodb.

  > It involves editing the registry, but service information can be found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services. Find the service you want to redirect, locate the ImagePath subkey and change that value.
- Go into a command prompt (may need to Run as Administrator) and do `sc delete mongod <or whatever the service is named>` -- can check services.msc for that).  Then re-run your command with the correct path.
- Alternately, you might try to set it up by taking a config file so that you can just change those options via config file rather than having to modify the service or delete/reinstall the service when you want to change options. I believe the command there is `C:\<mongopath>\mongod.exe -f <config file name> --install`.

Comment: No. 2 worked for me, i already made a new folder called "mongo" and copied relevant files but could not re-install due to it existing already, so sc delete mongod fixed it. thanks!