# How to configure Neo4j to use JDK 11 on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, neo4j

On Windows, my %JAVA_HOME% points to JDK 17 and I would like to keep it that way.

I would like to configure Neo4j to use JDK 11 then install it as a Windows service.

Just setting %JAVA_HOME% to JDK 11 on the command line allows to start Neo4j with "neo4j console" but I would like to have it installed with "neo4j install-service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like neo4j uses [Apache Commons Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon//index.html) to run its Java class as a service.

After running `Invoke-Neo4j install-service`, we can see the service generated in the Windows Service Pannel, which runs a command like `<NEO4J_HOME>\bin\tools\prunsrv-amd64.exe //RS//neo4j`.

One can check the command line options of `procrun` at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon//procrun.html. An option that might be useful is [`--JavaHome`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon//procrun.html#:%7E:text=JavaHome).

So, I think you can try modifying the Windows service generated by neo4j.

As for the ways to make some modification, here are some references:

- [Modifying the "Path to executable" of a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190480/modifying-the-path-to-executable-of-a-windows-service) on Stack Overflow;
- https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-windows-services-sc-exe/;