# Running a dll using rundll32.exe as a windows service

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, windows-services, rundll32

I was able to run a dll using rundll32.exe .

Now I want to run it as a windows service but it doesn't seem to start and gets timeout.

I am not sure how I could pass the parameters.

Trying something along the lines of ..

sc.exe create service binPath= "c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe -test.dll -Main"

Trying the suggestions from 
[creating a service with sc.exe; how to pass in context parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)
but it doesnt seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: What does not work? Did you check the Services Control Applet and review the commandline for `service`?

Answer (score 2):

rundll32.exe can't act as service! You need helper like srvany.exe (from old Resource Kit).

Comment: Hmm, I dont seem to have srvany.exe in Windows 7 and sc.exe cant run dll's as service..

Comment: As I said, srvany is a part of old Windows resource kit.

Comment: For the record, there's nothing in principle preventing a service from being implemented as a DLL and launched via rundll32.  I believe you're right in thinking that this isn't what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Harry Johnston, sorry for disappointing you, but "service" is much more complacated, rather than simple profram. For example, service must call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` on startup.

Comment: @Maximus: and you think a DLL can't call StartServiceCtrlDispatcher?  I've written several services, I'm familiar with the technology.

Comment: I think, that rundll32 does not call StartServiceCtrlDispatcher. That was I mentioned. But the Dll itself - can. This is true.