# Error when installing Apache 2.4 on windows - not logged in as administrator

Tags: apache2, installation

I am trying to setup Apache 2.4 on my windows vista following [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-apache-on-windows/). But I am getting an eror when I run the comman httpd -k install

// Error
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : AH00369: Failed to open the WinNT service manager, pe
rhaps you forgot to log in as Administrator?

I don't login as administrator set when I swith on my computer. And when I check  Control Panel, Administrative Tools, then Services Apache is not on the list.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: figured it out. Right click cmd and run as administrator

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Find cmd.exe and right click to select run as administrator 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the command line in Administrator mode.

[Opening Command Line window in Administrator mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOye4.png)

Note: Snap is from Windows 8.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thank you so much but i am still getting some error like below                          Installing the 'Apache2.4' service
The 'Apache2.4' service is successfully installed.
Testing httpd.conf....
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows server 2008, for some reason the command httpd -k install did not work (AH00369) even though I was in an Administrator command prompt.

However I was able to install the service using the sc command (references https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe and [When creating a service with sc.exe how to pass in context parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/when-creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters))

```
sc.exe create apache2.4 start= auto obj= "<username>" password= "<password>" DisplayName= "Apache 2.4" depend= "Tcpip/Afd" binpath= "\"c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\httpd.exe\" -k runservice"
```

username and password are necessary if you access network drives or UNC pathnames from apache