# Service does not start

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I created a Windows service with Delphi and used two method to install, start and stop.

**Method 1**

if i install this service using commandline

```
C:\MyService\ServiceApp.exe /Install
```

it installed successfully and i can start and stop too in the service console.

**Method 2**

but if i install the same service with different name using sc
e.g.

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc create myservice binpath= c:\MyService\ServiceApp.exe
```

I see it is installed but i can not start the service using service console as well as 
with

```
sc start myservice
```

when i do query using SC , result are as follows

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc query myservice

SERVICE_NAME: myservice
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
```

up till now i was using /Install but i want to install same service multiple times with different names, I got this idea of using from this post. ([How to install a windows service from command line specifying name and description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508628/how-to-install-a-windows-service-from-command-line-specifying-name-and-descripti))
can anybody explain difference of behavior between /Install and SC?

Comment: If you can show us the code you have which installs it and also which starts it, we might be able to help you.

Comment: To install:
sc create myservice binpath= c:\serviceapp\ServiceApp.exe
to start:
sc start myservice or simply start from service console

Comment: Please edit your question to include this critical information, not the comments.

Comment: hi jerry,In question i already how i installed the service in method 2

Comment: I can verify the problem on my box.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Now i have highlighted all the commands  in the question, I hope it is clear now,Thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding this, actually you didn't "already" have this in your question, you added it after I asked you to add it.

Comment: @Jerry: that info was actually in the original question. He only changed format, see the edits.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that was the actual command line used because it read as plain text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have clashed with a bug in `TService` implementation, see [QC #79781](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79781). Delphi is not able to start the service if the service name if different from `TService.Name`.

However, you can avoid this limitation by adjusting `TService.Name` before the service is started. One good point to do this is the `TService.OnCreate` event. You need to know the real name of the service, so you need to pass it as an argument to the service exe (adding it to the `binpath` of the `sc create` command).

**Create the service:**

```
sc create myservice1 binpath= "c:\MyService\ServiceApp.exe myservice1"
sc create myservice2 binpath= "c:\MyService\ServiceApp.exe myservice2"
```

**Adjust the name:**

```
procedure TMyService.ServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (System.ParamCount >= 1) and not CharInSet(ParamStr(1)[1], SwitchChars) then
    Name := ParamStr(1);
end;
```

This is a somewhat rudimentary method of argument parsing, but it is ok as an example. If the first argument doesn't start with `/` or `-`, it assumes that it's the supplied name.

**Remark:**

Another limitation of `TService` is that it can't create services (using `/install`) with arguments in their command line, because it uses `ParamStr(0)` as the `binpath`.

Comment: Well done! I was trying to figure out why SC was able to start the service when used with the real name.

Comment: @Sertac: It seems this bug is due to the system Delphi uses to allow sharing multiple `TService's` in one exe. I think that one simple solution will be to not check `Name` when there is only one TService.