# How to run loopback strongloop in windows server for production?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

How to run loopback strongloop in windows server for production, just like tomcat, it can automatic run while the server restarting, how can i do this? i just read the documentation it said i have to use Strongloop Project Manager.

i already install the project manager in my server, but i have to run the project manager with this command :

```
slc pm -l 7777
```

Then when i have to deploy to it with this command :

```
slc arc
```

but both command i have to run it in my loopback project. and i read some article it said, i have to install Project Manager as Service, how to install it as Windows Service?

in this article [How to install a windows service from command line specifying name and description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508628/how-to-install-a-windows-service-from-command-line-specifying-name-and-descripti)

they use to run .exe aplication, how can i run :

```
slc pm -l 777
```

in windows service? or there is something better i need to install beside windows service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a windows service from command line specifying name and description?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508628/how-to-install-a-windows-service-from-command-line-specifying-name-and-descripti)