# I cant install windows service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-services

I have created a windows service .It basically doesnt anything.The purpose is just to  register .After building the project  .I have launched  Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 and typed this command

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService3\WindowsService3\bin\Debug WindowsService3.exe
```

I got this message

```
Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Use
rs\xxx\Documents\visual' or one of its dependencies. Sytem coudnt find specified..........
```

Then I have tried  sc.exe and  nothing changed .And this is the  message

> SC] CreateService failed - 487: [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe /LogToConsole=true "Full path to exe goes there"`