# java program as a service

Tags: java, windows

I have no idea about the concept of java program as a service. I have developed a web service using spring framework and now I am asked to look on how to convert java program as a service. Can someone help me what is that about and the best way to convert as a service?

Comment: What has your googling turned up, and what questions do you have about what you found?

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way that I followed after many researches was Launch4j. It concerts the jar file to an executable. Then simply we can chanage it to services through sc create command. The following link will help to run as sercices.

[When creating a service with sc.exe how to pass in context parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/when-creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)