# What are the access rights required for a Python program to run as a service?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, service, windows-10

I have a few personal helper applications written in Python that communicate with me either through the Windows 10 taskbar area on the right (where the icons are - mine below is the red and blue square), or the Windows 10 Notification Center.

[image]

They currently run in a minimized shortcut (that points to `python.exe`) and I would like to remove them from the taskbar

[image]

The solution I am looking at is to run them as services. I created one (through [`nssm`](https://nssm.cc/)) and started the service that runs my program (via the `Local Service` account, which allows me to (hopefully) interact with the desktop). Unfortunately, I get

[image]

I allowed `MY-COMPUTER-NAME$` to access the working directory of the code, as well as to the script itself.

Is there something else I should allow for the script to successfully run?

(Note: the service started when I used my account, but the taskbar icon started from my program did not show up)

Answer (score 0):

I once used this command in cmd to run a service that is designed in python. follow this

```
sc create WojAPP binPath= "C:\Python34\Python.exe -- C:\tmp\yourpythonscript.py"
```

[reference][When creating a service with sc.exe how to pass in context parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)