# Using sc.exe in PowerShell does not create service with quotes

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services, registry

I try to create a service using **PowerShell** with following command in **PowerShell** script **(`.ps1`)**:

```
c:\windows\system32\sc.exe create "blaService" displayname= "blaService" binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\xxxx\xxx xxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx.exe\"" start= "auto"
```

Then I go to the **Registry Editor** and I see in the ImagePath field (corresponding to the service I've created)[image]:

The result I'd expect to get is the same but quoted, so basically `"C:\Program Files\xxxx\xxx xxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx.exe"`

I followed this thread: [When creating a service with sc.exe how to pass in context parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/when-creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters)

All comments guide to do the same as I did, so I don't understand where am I wrong

Comment: Why not use PowerShell's New-Service cmdlet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @endurium It's fine, but I also use `sc.exe failure`. What is the equivalent?

`c:\windows\system32\sc.exe failure "xxxx" reset= 5 actions= restart/5000`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process):

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

$sc_command = 'sc.exe create "blaService" displayname= "blaService" binpath= "\"d:\some path\to some.exe\"" start= "auto"'
$sc_command                              # make public command to process
$null = sc.exe delete blaService 2>$null # ensure that service does not exist
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2                   # give some time to finish

Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList '/C', $sc_command

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3                   # give some time to finish
                                         # and ensure properly quoted ImagePath
reg.exe query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\blaService -v ImagePath
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\73646083.ps1`

> ```
> sc.exe create "blaService" displayname= "blaService" binpath= "\"d:\some path\to some.exe\"" start= "auto"
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\blaService
>     ImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "d:\some path\to some.exe"
> ```

*Finally*, clear this absurd stuff from the registry:

```
sc.exe delete blaService
```

> [SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

It appears that escaping quotes is quite challenging there, but this works from PowerShell. Inner quotes are represented with 6 " signs.

```
sc.exe config "Grafana Agent" binpath= """""""C:\Program Files\Grafana Agent\grafana-agent-windows-amd64.exe"""""" -config.file=""""""C:\Grafana-Agent\grafana-agent-config.yaml"""""" -server.http.address=""""""0.0.0.0:12345"""""""
```

Comment: How do you know OP's issue is caused by quotes?