# Passing argument with sc create command in Inno Setup

Tags: c#, .net, inno-setup

I have a Inno Setup file containing code like :

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "https://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "Vytelle.DataService.Worker.exe"
#define MyAppAssocName MyAppName + " File"
#define MyAppAssocExt ".myp"
#define MyAppAssocKey StringChange(MyAppAssocName, " ", "") + MyAppAssocExt

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{72A0FB9B-516C-472D-886D-4DA0727FD72C}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
ChangesAssociations=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
OutputDir=D:\
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "D:\vytelle.dataservice\Vytelle.DataService\Vytelle.DataService.Worker\bin\Debug\net7.0\publish\win-x64\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExt}\OpenWithProgids"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueData: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppAssocName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1"""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\{#MyAppExeName}\SupportedTypes"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".myp"; ValueData: ""

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "create ByTestService start= auto binPath=""""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ThisisParameter" ; Flags: runhidden
```

But after installing, getting process code 1639 (wrong arguments error code)

[image]

Just want to know how to pass parameter with `sc create` command as you see in the run script of the give code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You are missing the trailing quote (needs to be doubled according to [Inno Setup syntax](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params)).
- The inner quotes in `binPath` need to be escaped.
  See [When creating a service with sc.exe how to pass in context parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3663331/850848)

So your commandline won't work even standalone, let alone in Inno Setup.

The correct syntax is:

```
"create ByTestService start= auto binPath=""\""{app}\{#MyAppExeName}\"" ThisisParameter"""
```

Note: the backslash in `\""` (twice) and the three trailing quotes `"""` (first two for trailing quote in `sc` `binPath` and the third to match the leading quote in `Parameters`).

This ultimately executes:

```
sc create ByTestService start= auto binPath="\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Accenture\Vytelle.DataService.Worker.exe\" ThisisParameter"
```

Comment: Genuinely Thank you for the quick response @Martin. It really works for me. I found an alternate way that you could get the same by registering the value in the imagePath variable in the registry editor of any service like
[Registry]
--Root: HKA; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ChiService"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "imagePath"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName} {code:GetParams}"

Comment: @HarisHussain Aren't you missing quotes around exe path in `ValueData`, in case the path contains quotes (what it does)?

Comment: No @Martin it will return the exact path with my given parameters but I'm using the approach which got from you. And I definitely give a thumbs up for the correct answer but I need 15 reputations to cast a vote that's why only accepting it but will surely do it when I get the reputations. Thanks