# Is there an official GUI way of installing and removing .Net services on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: user-interface, windows-server-2008, installutil

Please read the whole question; I personally think that **this is** programming-related; if you think otherwise, then please migrate without down-voting.

I have found two different ways of installing a service:
http://www.wsinnovations.com/softeng/support/manualservice.html

as well as using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx

The reason why I ask for this is that I am trying to debug a service which is somehow supposed to update itself. It is not currently working, but I was told that this did work in the past.

I have been using the `sc delete <servicename>` command to remove the service (because it is shorter that way), while installing it with an `installutil` command. I hope this does not result in any side-effects; I would like to rule those out.

Ideally, it should be possible to install and uninstall services right from the screen which lets the user start and stop them, but such option is not does not exist unfortunately. I am looking for the next best thing, which is a GUI wrapper for installutil.exe

Comment: You could always write one..? It wouldn't take much to wrap the commands. Stick it up on CodePlex if you think others would benefit from it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - not in the way I believe you're thinking of. The GUI way would be as part of an MSI or other installer, which calls the same APIs as installutil does.

So what you could do is write an installer which can run silently, and then use that to install and uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look here to get an impression of the underlying API: [Install a .NET windows service without InstallUtil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255056/install-a-net-windows-service-without-installutil-exe)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an installer using one of the many installation frameworks out there.  I personally use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) and there are a bunch of [examples](http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2007/05/how-to-install-windows-service-using.html) out there about how to write these sorts of things.